# Caching and saving videos in tableview

Tags: objective-c, caching

I'm displaying videos with tableview and would like to save urls/data in cache so user won't have to download the same video again when replayed.

However I'd like to keep them only until user quits the app. The next time he opens the app he'll have to download them again so I only need to save them for the app's active lifetime.

Should I still do caching or is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
-(void)loadVideo:(NSString *)urlString {


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSString* cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* file = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/EGOCache.plist"];
NSDictionary *dict =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];

if ([dict objectForKey:urlString] )
{
    NSData *data = [[EGOCache globalCache] dataForKey:urlString];
    data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
            [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                 returningResponse:nil
                                             error:nil];
    NSLog(@"loading from cache %@",urlString);

}else{
    NSData  *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:
                     [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]
                                          returningResponse:nil
                                                      error:nil];
    [[EGOCache globalCache] setData:data forKey:urlString];
    NSLog(@"saving cache %@",urlString);

}
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 10.0];
[self.videoPlayer setContentURL:[request URL]];}
```

Answer (score 0):

`AVFoundation` allows for streaming a video file on disk.
I suggest you look into saving the video in the Documents folder or Caches folder and steam it to `AVFoundation` from there. Then when the user quits the app, `applicationWillTerminate` gets called and you can wipe the videos from disk.

EDIT

Using MPMoviePlayerController:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: URL-TO-FILE-ON-DISK];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
[myView addSubview: player.view];
// ...
[player play];
```

Comment: I'm using MPMoviePlayerController. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by URL-TO-FILE-ON-DISK. Updated the question. (Btw something's wrong with my code. I don't think it's saving in cache)